# Crediting imagery provider after delineating polygon using satellite imagery

Tags: license, world-imagery

I would like to create a polygon layer of wetlands for example. If I use satellite imagery to delineate the features, does that mean that the vector polygon is a derivative/modification  of the imagery?

I would like to create and distribute a vector dataset with a very lax licence, but I want to make sure I am truly permitted to distribute it under a highly open license.

Comment: You used your resources to create your polygon (your time and knowledge) and used the imagery as a reference.  I like to think of it like a pie - if you buy a pie from a bakery, you wouldn't tell your family that you made it, even if you put a bit of garnish on it to make it look better.  However, if you buy a pie crust and pie filling and put it together and bake it in your oven, You made that pie.  You might give some credit to the crust and filling makers, but the pie is still your creation.  Just my thoughts on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few complicating factors that go into this:

1. What your application is,
2. What the licensing agreements of the source data are.

There are some datasets that require attribution, like the ones from the US Census and NASA, and allow modification and translation. It really should not be very onerous to meet attribution requirements in a footnote or an included file, and usually, the accompanying documentation will tell you how to do it.

In the case where attribution is not required, it's still a good idea to do so, if nothing else, to keep a record of your own work, but, also, to create goodwill and visibility for the contributor of your inputs.

TL;DR: If it's not required by the license, nobody can make you, but you should.

Comment: Thanks Dheeraj, as an example, the ESA sentinel dataset mentions attributing them if the works contains modified sentinel data. I was wondering if creating a new item by delineation constituted modification? https://sentinel.esa.int/documents/247904/690755/Sentinel_Data_Legal_Notice